# If none of checkbox checked then give alert if atleast one checkbox checked so no alert in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        Run = function () {
        var oTable = document.getElementById("tblVendorData");

        var strArticleCode = "";

        var j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < oTable.rows.length; i++) {

            var elem = oTable.rows[i].cells[0].children[0];

            if (elem.checked == true) {

                if (j == 0) {
                    strArticleCode = elem.id;
                }
                else {

                    strArticleCode += "," + elem.id;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Above works if we have lot of records in checkbox. But if we did not check any check box so give a alert.. `Alert ("Please check atlaest one checkbox")`.
if any checked so no alert and submit..
So how can write alert inside this code..

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code, specifically anything relating to submission?

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on what you've provided, you could do some quick counting within your loop, and verification after your for loop:

```
    Run = function () {
    var oTable = document.getElementById("tblVendorData");

    var strArticleCode = "";

    var j = 0;
    var num_checked = 0; // Initiate variable = 0

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.rows.length; i++) {

        var elem = oTable.rows[i].cells[0].children[0];

        if (elem.checked == true) {
            num_checked++; // Increment variable since this is checked

            if (j == 0) {
                strArticleCode = elem.id;
            }
            else {

                strArticleCode += "," + elem.id;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if ( num_checked < 1 ){ // Was anything checked?
            alert( "You must check at least one option.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the checkbox element and if find all of them are not checked then make an alert. You can make use of a flag.

```
A : <input type="checkbox" />
B : <input type="checkbox" />
C : <input type="checkbox" />
D : <input type="checkbox" />
```

***jQuery :***

```
var isChecked = false;

$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        isChecked = true;
    }
});

if(!isChecked){
    alert("Please check atlaest one checkbox");
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/06jchpy7/)

Answer (score 0):

## Native javascript way:

```
Run = function () {
    var oTable = document.getElementById("tblVendorData"),
        srtArticleCode = "",
        articleCode = [],
        j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < oTable.rows.length; i++) {

        var elem = oTable.rows[i].cells[0].children[0];

        if (elem.checked == true) articleCode.push(elem.id);     
    }
    
    if(articleCode.length === 0){
        alert("Please check atlaest one checkbox");
    }else{
        var srtArticleCode = articleCode.join();
    }
}
```

This row:

`if (elem.checked == true) articleCode.push(elem.id);`

test if the checkbox is `checked` and if is `true` add the id to an array.
Than out of the loop:

```
if(articleCode.length === 0){
    alert("Please check atlaest one checkbox");
}else{
    var srtArticleCode = articleCode.join();
    //alert(srtArticleCode);
}
```

if the array is empty perform the alert else `articleCode.join()` return a string: `1,2,4..` - `{ID1},{ID2},{ID3},{ID4}...`

Try yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/2d79u1va/

### jQuery way:

```
Run = function () {
    var $cked = $('#tblVendorData [type=checkbox]:checked');
    if($cked.length === 0) return alert("Please check atlaest one checkbox");
    var articleCode = [];
    $cked.each(function(){
        articleCode.push(this.id); 
    });
    var srtArticleCode = articleCode.join();
    //alert(srtArticleCode);
}
```

Try yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/2d79u1va/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class "checkboxClass" on your checkbox. Use below codes to get the checked and total checkboxes.

```
var checkboxCount = $('.checkboxClass').length;
var checkboxCheckedCount = $('.checkboxClass:checked').length;
if (checkboxCheckedCount == 0) {
    alert ("Please check atlaest one checkbox");
}
```